# Laravel | Call variable in view

Tags: php, laravel

I need help figuring out what I'm doing wrong. I'm building a chat where on the right side I have the users and when clicking on the user opens the respective chat.

In the users on the right I put the following HREF:

```
<a href="{{route('chat.index', ['id'=>$item->id])}}">
```

Which then shows the following link on the page:

```
/Chat?id=10
```

I put in the view if there is id shows the chat.

```
@if ($id)
```

But don't come here. I can't get the IF to be true.

In the controller I have the following code, but I don't think it's wrong.

```
$outroUser = null;

if($id){
    $outroUser = utilizador::findOrFail($id); 
}

$tabela = utilizador::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

return view('painel-admin.chat.index', ['itens' => $tabela, $outroUser]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get id param you can try following in your controller

```
if ($request->has('id')) {
    $outroUser = utilizador::findOrFail($request->query('id'));
}
```

Do not forget to add Request object into your controller function params

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function yourController(Request $request) {
   //Code
}
```